# What places does the Russian visa waiver cover?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, russia, visa-free-entry

I saw [this](http://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/indians-can-visit-russia-s-far-east-without-visas-says-dmitry-medvedev-117041800497_1.html) item in my news feed. It says that Russia has waived the need for nationals from 18 countries including India to have a visa to visit the Russian Far East.

I wanted to know what cities this covers and if there are additional requirements like specific ports of entry and exit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According the text of [this federal law](http://government.ru/en/docs/27292/) (link [in Russian](http://government.ru/activities/selection/525/26714/)):

> Иностранные граждане, прибывающие через пункты пропуска через государственную границу России, расположенные на территории свободного порта Владивосток, на основании электронных виз, имеют право на свободу передвижения **в пределах территории субъекта Федерации, на которую осуществлен въезд**. Из Российской Федерации такие иностранные граждане выезжают **через пункты пропуска свободного порта Владивосток**.

So it basically says, that you can freely go anythere you can **inside** Russian Federation region you've entered. In this case, for Vladivostok, it means that you can visit any places available **inside** [Primorsky Krai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorsky_Krai), as it has Vladivostok as it's capital. Also, you need to **enter/exit the Russia from Vladivostok**'s border control check points, and only there.

However, it's not clear in English version, does the region corresponds to [whole Far East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Far_East) or only [Primorsky Krai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorsky_Krai). But in Russian it clearly states **Russian Federation' subject**, so this law is about [Primorsky Krai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorsky_Krai).

You can apply for visa on special site, and can stay inside for up to 8 days per visa, without any consulate fee, visa will be one-visit type, valid for 30 days. You'll have to apply in minimum 4 days before entrance the Russia.

Text of amendment law in Russian can be found [here](http://kremlin.ru/acts/bank/41744). Text of official comments in English can be found [here](http://en.kremlin.ru/acts/news/54003).

**Update**: (based on [this article](http://www.newsvl.ru/far_east/2017/04/18/158452/)): this option to enter Russia is planned to be available from August, 1st. Testing of the border control checkpoints starts from June, 1st. There are plans to introduce such scheme in all the Far East regions with free ports: [Primorsky Krai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorsky_Krai), [Kamchatka Krai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamchatka_Krai), [Chukotka Autonomous Okrug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukotka_Autonomous_Okrug), [Khabarovsk Krai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khabarovsk_Krai), [Sakhalin Oblast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakhalin_Oblast). [Magadan Oblast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magadan_Oblast) do have plans to introduce Magadan as a free port ([article in Russian](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/3243210)), but for now they do not have this option.